# Use RECID as primary key in OpenEdge TEMP-TABLE

Tags: dataset, temp-tables, openedge, progress-4gl

I would like to create a dataset containing a couple of temp-tables that are filled by an xml file.

```
DEF TEMP-TABLE ttOrder NO-UNDO
    FIELD iOrderNo AS INT
    FIELD iOrderDate AS DATE
    INDEX ix RECID. // This also won't work, but this is needed to use the `OF` statement when retrieving records.

DEF TEMP-TABLE ttOrderLine NO-UNDO
    FIELD iParent AS RECID
    FIELD iArticleNo AS INT
    FIELD dPrice AS DECIMAL.

DEF DATASET dsOrder FOR ttOrder, ttOrderLine
    DATA-RELATION Order_OrderLine FOR ttOrder, ttOrderLine
    RELATION-FIELDS ttOrder.RECID, ttOrderLine.iParent. // This is what won't work, but what I would like to do.
```

Usually I would just create an `iOrderNo` field in `ttOrderLine` and match that in the datasets `RELATION-FIELDS` attribute. Since the data is loaded from an XML file, this will be tough.

The end goal is that instead of this:

```
FIND FIRST ttOrder.
FOR EACH ttOrderLine WHERE ttOrderLine.iParent = RECID(ttOrder):
    // Do something
END.
```

I would like to do this:

```
FIND FIRST ttOrder.
FOR EACH ttOrderLine of ttOrder:
    // Do something
END.
```

The error I get now when using the last method is `Index field of table1 must be fields in table2`.

Could someone tell me how I can get this done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Temp-Table records RECID's will change whenever the temp-table is passed around by-value (not by-reference) and passed between client and AppServer.

Generally using RECID's as keys in other tables is a very dangerous scenario.

So your scenario would break anyway, if the dataset with the Order RECID's in the Orderline table is populated on an AppServer and processed on a client.

Comment: A very good point indeed. @MikeFechner. How would you solve this if I don't have access to the orderid when loading the orderline?

Comment: IMHO you'll have to have a keyfield in Order which is referenced in OrderLine. If you don't have (access to) a PUK field or Order, use a GUID. The ABL GUID function will provide a GUID value whenever needed.

Comment: @MikeFechner Would it be possible to use that in a temp-tables and the dataset?

Comment: Yes. Although I don't understand your question fully. Datasets are a collection of temp-tables. Datasets don't have fields by themselves. You can use a GUID field (type CHARACTER) as a field in temp-tables and that field can be used on the data-relation in a ProDataset.

Comment: @MikeFechner What I would like to achieve is to load an XML content into a dataset. The problem is that the child nodes do not contain a foreign key to the parent node. Therefore I used the RECID in the first instance, because then I can use `PARENT-ID-RELATION`. But that raises some issues as you already pointed out. But now I do not have a way to add a foreign key to the "child"  temp-tables so they can be retrieved. So the "child" temp-table should fill a field with a value of the " parent" temp-tables primary key.

Comment: I've done exactly like this when reading xml's into datasets and then passed the dataset BY-REFERENCE. It works. Another option is to populate the temp-tables with an id. Could be a guid or a simple counter-id - whatever rocks your boat.

Answer (score -2):

For the `OF`syntax to work you need to store the parent ID in a unique index in the child table.

The dataset isn't needed for this syntax but if you indeed also need a dataset using recid you should look into `PARENT-ID-RELATION` instead of `RELATIONS-FIELDS`.

Start by looking at this:

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttOrder NO-UNDO
    FIELD iOrderNo   AS INTEGER
    FIELD iOrderDate AS DATE
    FIELD iParent    AS RECID.


DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttOrderLine NO-UNDO
    FIELD iParent    AS RECID
    FIELD iArticleNo AS INTEGER
    FIELD dPrice     AS DECIMAL
    INDEX ix IS UNIQUE iParent.


DEFINE DATASET dsOrder FOR ttOrder, ttOrderLine
    PARENT-ID-RELATION Order_OrderLine FOR ttOrder, ttOrderLine PARENT-ID-FIELD iParent.


FOR EACH ttOrder, EACH ttOrderLine OF ttOrder:
    DISPLAY ttOrder.
    DISPLAY ttOrderLine.
END.
```

Comment: I would suggest commenting when downvoting. This solution does indeed solve the problem at hand (if recids and temp-tables are a good idea or not might depend on the situation).

Comment: A key, but perhaps subtle, thing that jensd points out is that OF does not require RECID.  It just requires that the field name exists in both tables and that is uniquely indexed.